# Internal Server Error when deploying Chalice (AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chalice

I am trying to deploy a simple REST API using Chalice. My basic boilerplate is

```
from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

When I call chalice local and run it on localhost 8000, there is no issue and I am able to get back the returns. However, after I deployed it and used the REST API URL that was returned, it didn't work anymore. I keep getting the

> {"message": "Internal server error"}

I would appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Might be API Gateway setting. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-troubleshooting-lambda.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Good news, it looks like you are reaching your lambda.
2. Check aws cloudwatch logs: /aws/lambda/helloworld-{dev|prod}
3. If can't solve it, upload .chalice/config.json and the error of the logs in clouwatch